# Applying a formula to the data in several files

Tags: import, data

I am calculating with the depth data recorded in a number of files with extension .log.

The depth data is like this and I loaded it by means of *Mathematica*:

```
Import["C:\\Homeworks\\depth\\file1.log"]
```

> ```
> {"2016/01/13 00:00:30", 42, 754}, {"2016/01/13 00:01:00", 42, 754}, 
> {"2016/01/13 00:01:30", 42, 753}, {"2016/01/13 00:02:00", 42, 752}, 
> {"2016/01/13 00:02:30", 42, 753}, {"2016/01/13 00:03:00", 42, 754}
> ```

I succeed in obtaining the depth data and transforming it into
`42.754, 42.754, 42.753, 42.752, 42.753, 42.754`, etc.

However, this only processes the data in one file. However, I have in my folder a group of about 10 files. How can I read in all the data in a folder in an easier way than to do it individually?

Comment: Look at the docs for `FileNames[ ]` , `Map[ ]` and perhaps `Flatten[ ___,1]`. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that your file names are file1.log, file2.log,...,file10.log try the following

```
Table[Import[i], {i, FileNames["C:\\Homeworks\\depth\\file*.log"]}]
```

The context of FileName command should be the directory containing your files.

Comment: Absolutely, Mr. demm your answer  captured the main  problem.
Dr. Belisaruis Flatten[ __,1] was also nice trick.